# Faster way of finding multiple of double

Tags: c, optimization, floating-point

If have the following C function, used to determine if one number is a multiple of another to an arbirary tolerance

```
#include <math.h>

#define TOLERANCE 0.0001

int IsMultipleOf(double x,double mod)
{
    return(fabs(fmod(x, mod)) < TOLERANCE);
}
```

It works fine, but profiling shows it to be very slow, to the extent that it has become a candidate for optimization.  About 75% of the time is spent in `modulo` and the remaining in `fabs`.  I'm trying to figure a way of speeding things up, using something like a look-up table.  The parameter `x` changes regularly, whereas `mod` changes infrequently.  The number of possible values of x is small enough that the space for a look-up would not be an issue, typically it will be one of a few hundred possible values.  I can get rid of the `fabs` easily enough, but can't figure out a reasonable alternative to the modulo.  Any ideas on how to optimize the above?

**Edit**  The code will be running on a wide range of Windows desktop and mobile devices, hence processors could include Intel, AMD on desktop, and ARM or SH4 on mobile devices.  VisualStudio 2008 is the compiler.

Comment: What is `modulo` ? Is this your own function ? Why are you not using `fmod` ?

Comment: @Paul R - My bad, modulo is actually defined as fmod in this case, question edited.

Comment: @Andrei Ciobanu - `bool` is defined in `stdbool.h` in C99.

Comment: What's the environment - do you have an FPU?

Comment: @Roddy, the environment is Windows desktop, and Windows mobile on a variety of devices.  Desktop will always have FPU, mobile devices are ARM based so I'm not sure of floating point capability there.

Comment: It sounds strange that profiling marked that part so expensive! If there are fpus, they are as fast as possible in hardware; they could be enhanced with some bit-tricks maybe (e.g. see http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html but here there's nothing for IEEE and "fmod"), but you could need conditional compilations for your different targets to be sure to have always the optimal performance... you could stick to integers, but it depends on the problem you're handling and the required precision...

Comment: The ARM processor may or may not have an FPU, if it doesn't, I recommend swapping to fixed point numbers. Its a bit more work, but it will run a LOT faster than floats/doubles and if your value ranges aren't too extreme, there should be no detriment to using it.

Comment: +1 for having profiled.  If I had a nickel for everybody who posted some sort of microoptimization question without having profiled....

Answer (score 3):

Do you really have to use `modulo` for this?

Wouldn't it be possible to just `result = x / mod` and then check if the decimal part of `result` is close to 0. For instance:

```
11 / 5.4999 = 2.000003  ==> 0.000003 < TOLERANCE
```

Or something like that.

Comment: pretty sure that's exactly what `modulo` or `fmod` does (: only it may do it a *smarter* way depending on the CPU (it may be a single instruction for example to calculate the division and modulus together)

Comment: @drfrogsplat - My assumption was that fmod and division were going to have similar performance, but this is something I should obviously test.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to inspect the bowels of your C RTL `fmod()` function: X86 FPU's have '[FPREM/FPREM1](http://www.sesp.cse.clrc.ac.uk/html/SoftwareTools/vtune/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc109.htm)' instructions which computes remainders by repeated subtraction.

While floating point division is a single instruction, it seems you may need to call FPREM repeatedly to get the right answer for modulus, so your RTL may not use it.

Comment: yes this is good advice. If you build with -O3 -ffast-math or other high level of optimization, gcc may use fprem when implementing fmod() to avoid calling a libm function. I have seen this in generated asm for 4.6, 9.4, and 11.3

Answer (score 1):

Division (floating point or not, `fmod` in your case) is often an operation where the execution time varies a lot depending on the cpu and compiler:

- gcc has a builtin replacement for
  that if you give it the right compile
  flags or if you use `__builtin_fmod` 
  explicitly. This then might map the
  operation on a small number of
  assembler instructions.
- there may be special units like SSE
  on intel processors where this
  operation is implemented more
  efficiently

By such tricks, depending on your environment (you didn't tell which) the time may vary from some clock cycles to some hundred. I think best is to look into the documentation of your compiler and cpu for that particular operation.

Comment: SSE would only help if you want to perform several divisions at once (actually I'm not even sure if SSE instructions include division).

The second 'S' is for 'SIMD' = Single Instruction Multiple Data, i.e. perform 8 additions at once, so I think this'd only help if one were to be searching for valid 'mod' values by testing a large list of them (i.e. you could test 8 at once, perhaps)...

Comment: No, this S in there is only for historical reasons. You have some instructions that are faster if you use them just for one operator. But the downside is really that there is not one simple rule for it. You have to dig through manuals, realize different implementations and benchmark the whole to know what is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The following is probably overkill, and sub-optimal.  But for what it is worth here is one way on how to do it.

We know the format of the double ...

- 1 bit for the sign
- 11 bits for the biased exponent
- 52 fraction bits

Let ...

- value = x / mod;
- exp = exponent bits of value - BIAS;
- lsb = least sig bit of value's fraction bits;

Once you have that ...

```
/*
 * If applying the exponent would eliminate the fraction bits
 * then for double precision resolution it is a multiple.
 * Note: lsb may require some massaging.
 */
if (exp > lsb)
    return (true);

if (exp < 0)
    return (false);
```

The only case remaining is the tolerance case.  Build your double so that you are getting rid of all the digits to the left of the decimal.

- sign bit is zero (positive)
- exponent is the BIAS (1023 I think ... look it up to be sure)
- shift the fraction bits as appropriate

Now compare it against your tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this at all, but from the way I understand fmod this should be equivalent inlined, which might let the compiler optimize it better, though I would have thought that the compiler's math library (or builtins) would work just as well.  (also, I don't even know for sure if this is correct).

```
#include <math.h>

int IsMultipleOf(double x, double mod) {
    long n = x / mod;  // You should probably test for /0 or NAN result here
    double new_x = mod * n;
    double delta = x - new_x;
    return fabs(delta) < TOLERANCE;  // and for NAN result from fabs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get away with long long instead of double if you have comparable scale of data. For example `long long` would be enough for over [60 astronomical units in micrometer resolution](http://www.google.com/search?q=2%5e63+micrometer+in+au).

Answer (score 0):

Does it *need* to be double precision ? Depending on how good your math library is, this ought to be faster:

```
#include <math.h>

#define TOLERANCE 0.0001f

bool IsMultipleOf(float x, float mod)
{
    return(fabsf(fmodf(x, mod)) < TOLERANCE);
}
```

Comment: fmodf() is *slower* than fmod().

Comment: @Hans Passant: that will depend on what CPU and math library you are using - in general it *should* be faster.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I just tested this on a Core i7, compiling with Intel ICC 11, and the single precision version with `fmodf` is around 25% faster. **YMMV** of course.

Answer (score 0):

I presume modulo looks a little like this on the inside:

```
mod(x,m) {
  while (x > m) {
    x = x - m
  }
  return x
}
```

I think that through some sort of search i could be optimised: eg:

```
fastmod(x,m) {
  q = 1

  while (m * q < x) {
    q = q * 2
  }

  return mod((x - (q / 2) * m), m)
}
```

You might even choose to replace the finall call to mod with annother call to fastmod, adding the condition that if x < m then to return x.